# How to rename a folder the same as the filename of the first file inside that folder using Windows batch programming?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, renaming

I have a group of about 3,000 folders named XYZ-1 through XYZ-3000. Inside those folders are groups of image files and a description text file. Such as:

- Property123_0001.jpg
- Property123_0002.jpg
- Property123_0003.jpg
- ...
- Property123_0085.jpg
- Property123_0086.jpg
- Z_Description.txt

The number of `.jpg` files differs in each folder, but there's always a single description file. Each directory's image files have a different name, for example `XYZ-1 might contain Property123, while XYZ-10 might contain Easement789.

I need to rename the folders containing the files after the "Property123" part of the .jpg files. Ideally I would truncate off the trailing digits and the underscore, but even if they were left on, it would be better than the XYZ-1 names.

I'm working on a batch file to do just that, but mine won't run and I can't figure out why.

Here's what I have:

```
for /d %%D in (*) do (
   set "_dir=%%D"
   set /a "_first=1"
   cd "%%D"
   for %%F in (*) do (
      if %_first%==1 set "_name=%%~nF"
      set /a "_first=0"
   )
   cd ..
   ren %_dir% %_name%
)
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, the command window just closes immediately. I tried putting a pause command at the end, but that didn't keep the window open. Nothing happens to the files/folders.

I've tried my syntax from a command line and everything looks OK. So I don't know what the problem is. Can I get a little help, please?

Comment: What numeric digits are you talking about concerning truncating: the ones after the `_`, or also the ones before (`123` in your sample file list)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%D in (*) do (
   set "_dir=%%D"
   set "_name=%%D"
   set /a "_first=1"
   cd "%%D"
   for %%F in (*) do (
      if !_first!==1 set "_name=%%~nF"
      set /a "_first=0"
   )
   cd ..
   ren !_dir! !_name!
)
```

You need to use setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion here, and use ! instead of % inside for loops.

I also added set "_name=%%D" so it won't try to change a second folder to the first folders name if that folder doesn't contain files

EDIT:

also takes into consideration the underscore part:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%D in (*) do (
   set "_dir=%%D"
   set "_name=%%D"
   set /a "_first=1"
   cd "%%D"
   for %%F in (*) do (
      if !_first!==1 (
        set "_name=%%~nF"
        set /a "_first=0"
        if NOT "!_name!"=="!_name:_=!" (
          set "subfix=!_name:*_=!"
          for /f "delims=" %%B in ("!subfix!") do set "_name=!_name:_%%B=!"
        )
      )
   )
   cd ..
   ren !_dir! !_name!
)
```

Comment: I'm definitely going to have to read up on the ! indicator and the delayed expansion. I've never used those before an don't really know what they do.

Comment: If my answer solved your probmlem, you should mark it as correct by clicking the check to the left of it.

Comment: I'll try to get the underscore part working tomorrow but that'll be a lot harder

Comment: Edited: was easier than I thought. By the way, wouldn't it be easier to check if the extension of the file is .txt (`"%%~xF"==".txt"`) instead of if it is the first file?

Comment: Yes, but I'm thinking I can use a simple file/folder renaming util I have to remove the "_0001" from the ends of the folder names, so this works well because it's guaranteed to grab the first file, thus making all of them the same number.

Comment: The _0001 removal is already being done with my second answer

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks again!