# Powershell - Take a fix amount of files and move them to new folder

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a powershell script like this one I have found:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |  # Get files
  Group-Object { $_.Name -replace '_.*' } |  # Group by part before first underscore
  ForEach-Object {
    # Create directory
    $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.Name
    # Move files there
    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir
  }
```

But with the difference, that the group-object should take a fix amount of 5 files from folder A, creates a new folder named by the first file, and move the 5 files in the new folder. See example picture below (the file names differs).
I am a bloody beginer in powershell so if possible please keep the advice simple ;)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttwbb.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VO3F.jpg)
Thanks and regards!

Comment: @Paul: The `Group-Object` groups the input files by shared filename prefix before the (first) `_` in the filename. The `ForEach-Object` then operates on each resulting group, creating a directory named for the shared prefix, and moves all files in the group to that new directory.

Comment: @nosediver: Do you simply want to only take the first 5 files _from each group_? If you want to partition across groups, it is unclear what logic you're looking for. Please clarify by updating your question directly.

Comment: Change the grouping to be a counter divided by 5 and rounded up to the nearest whole number `$n = 0; Get-ChildItem -File | Group-Object -Property {$script:n++; [math]::Ceiling($n/5)} | ForEach-Object {  your code here }` might do it

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Thank you. It seams it works a little bit. Result:
The script lists the the files correct, but the naming is wrong, it starts just by the number 5,(next gruop 6 and so on) no letters.

And there are some errors for the New-Item:

+     $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.Name
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: ("path") [New- 
   Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

And in result to the first error the Move-Item cant work.

Comment: Sorry, missed the first, the numbering of the groups starts by 1, not 5, like I had written!

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler But it still does not work. Did I do something wrong? `$n = 0; Get-ChildItem -File | Group-Object -Property {$script:n++; [math]::Ceiling($n/5)}`
` ForEach-Object {`
    `# Create directory`
   ` $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.group[0].Name`
  `  # Move files there`
   ` $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir`
  `}`

_+     $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.group[0].Name_
_    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException_
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray_

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler 
Better readable version [link](http://imgur.com/a/gC0fu). Error:
[Link](http://imgur.com/a/44ULP)

Comment: You need a `|` to connect the output of `Group-Object` into the input of `ForEach-Object`.  `Group-Object -Property {..} | ForEach-Object {..}`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Great, works well! I hardly dare to ask, but is there an easy way to extract the filename from every first file in the group for each new created foldername?

Comment: Not sure I'm following; `$.group[0].Name` is the filename of the first file in the group, isn't it? `$.group[0].BaseName` is the filename without extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Vitaly! The solution works well.
Here is the complete script:

```
$n = 0; Get-ChildItem -File | Group-Object -Property {$script:n++; [math]::Ceiling($n/5)} | 
ForEach-Object { 
$dname = $_.group.name    
$fname=$dname 
$fl = $fname[0].Split(".")[0]
    $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $fl                      

    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TessellatingHeckler, it works well.

```
$n = 0; Get-ChildItem -File | Group-Object -Property {$script:n++; [math]::Ceiling($n/5)} | 
ForEach-Object {                               
    $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.Name   # Create directory
    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir          # Move files there
}
```

For the renaming-part I'm using a batch from @Dennis van Gils ([How to rename a folder the same as the filename of the first file inside that folder using Windows batch programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345588/how-to-rename-a-folder-the-same-as-the-filename-of-the-first-file-inside-that-fo))
I am sure there is a way doing it together with the powershell part, but this solution works for me to.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello. You can also try this, if you want to creates a new folder named by the first file:

```
ForEach-Object { 
$dname = $_.group.name    
$fname=$dname.replace(".","")    
$fl = $fname[0]
    $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $fl                      

    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir
```

Comment: Thank you Vitaly. Works perfect! It just needs to delete the file ending in the foldernames.

Comment: If you dont need to use file extension you may to replace this $fname=$dname.replace(".","")    
$fl = $fname[0] on this: $fname=$dname $fl = $fname[0].Split(".")[0]